# ui-select change color on focus doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CHY6lqVfVQuMoAmxyvlL?p=preview) I have a ui-select that allows multiple entries. I changed the `border` color to blue, and tried to change the color to red when `ui-select` gets the focus using `.font-control:focus` but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

HTML

```
  <style>
    .form-control {
      border-color: blue;
    }
    .form-control:focus {
      border-color: red;
    }
  </style>

    <br/><br/>
      <ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="(custom 'new' label)" 
          ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" sortable="true" 
           style="width: 300px;" title="Choose a color">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
              {{color}}
            </ui-select-choices>
       </ui-select>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.select']);
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

      $scope.availableColors = ['Red','Green','Blue','Yellow','Magenta',
                                 'Maroon','Umbra','Turquoise'];

      $scope.multipleDemo = {};
      $scope.multipleDemo.colors = ['Blue','Red'];


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you can't be able to focus the outside tag, the `ui-select` replaced by a `div`.

If you want to change the border color when you click the whole tags, you just need to modify the style code like below:

```
.ui-select-multiple.ui-select-bootstrap {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
body > .ui-select-bootstrap.open {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Because the `ui-select` will add the `open` class when you click to open dropdown menu, you can use it to do something you want.But notice that the way change the style above is global, so I will suggest you to add parent class before it:

```
<style>
    .your-custom-class .ui-select-multiple.ui-select-bootstrap {
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    .your-custom-class > .ui-select-bootstrap.open {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>

<div class="your-custom-class">
    <ui-select multiple tagging tagging-label="(custom 'new' label)" 
              ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" sortable="true" 
               style="width: 300px;" title="Choose a color">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
         <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
              {{color}}
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

Comment: please take a look at this plunk, the border doesn't change to red on focus http://plnkr.co/edit/mkm42Dxet4zoAdSqSdMv?p=preview

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake, you should remove the `body` of the `.your-custom-class body > .ui-select-bootstrap.open`,instead:

Comment: instead:`.your-custom-class > .ui-select-bootstrap.open`